# Solving $\sin(2v) = \sin(v)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\sin(2v) = \sin(v)$$
Why can't this equation be solved by setting:
$$2v = v + 2\pi n \quad \leftrightarrow  \quad v = 2\pi n\\2v = \pi - v + 2\pi n \quad\leftrightarrow \quad 3v = \pi + 2\pi n  \quad \leftrightarrow \quad v = \frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{2\pi n}{3}$$

This is how I've seen other similar equations being solved.

Please note that I was able to solve the equation by setting $\sin(2v) = 2\sin(v)\cos(v)$, I just want to know why this particular equation not can be solved the way I presented.

The correct solutions are (according to my literature): $v = \pi n$ or $v = \pm \frac{\pi}{3} + 2\pi n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that both your solutions and the solutions in the literature repeat with a period of $2\pi$, so it's enough to check that they're the same within the $2\pi$-long interval $[-\pi, \pi)$.

In that interval, the literature's solutions are:

- $v=\pi n$, leading to $v=-\pi$ or $v=0$ (for $n=-1$ or $n=0$)
- $v=\pm \frac{\pi}{3} + 2\pi n$, leading to $v = -\frac{\pi}{3}$ or $v=\frac{\pi}{3}$ (for $n=0$).

while your solutions are:

- $v=2\pi n$, leading to $v=0$
- $v=\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{2\pi n}{3}$, leading to $v=-\pi$, $v=-\frac{\pi}{3}$, or $v=\frac{\pi}{3}$ (for $n=-2,-1,0$ respectively).

That is, you get all the same solutions as the book; they're just split up differently.

Comment: Thank you! And I assume it doesn't matter which way you solve the equation? Or is there a preferred way?

Comment: @lawls: It doesn't matter; either way works just as well. It's good to have both in your mental toolbox, because you could run into other equations where one of them works well, and the other one fails or becomes really hard to work out the details of...

Answer (score 4):

You can solve it by your method as well and your answer is right.

---

**EDIT**

Let us look at the solutions of the form $\dfrac{\pi}3 + \dfrac{2\pi n}3$. $n$ an be only of the form $3k$ or $3k \pm 1$.

- If $n=3k$, we obtain the solution to be $2k\pi + \dfrac{\pi}3$
- If $n=3k+1$, we obtain the solution to be of the form $2k\pi + \pi$
- If $n=3k-1$, we obtain the solution to be of the form $2k\pi - \dfrac{\pi}3$

The above along with the solution $2k \pi$ gives you all the possibilities as the other solution.

Comment: I've added the correct solutions to my answer, could you motivate why they are equal to mine?